# Show that coefficients of DE are of the form $p_j(z) = \sum_{k=0}^j p_{jk}(z-1)^{-k}$ iff it has regular singularities in $0,1,\infty$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a problem with proving the *following statement*:

We consider the linear differential equation

$$\theta^n + p_1 \theta^{n-1} + ... +p_{n-1}\theta + p_n = 0$$ with $$\theta = z \frac{d}{dz}$$

and $p_j \in \mathbb{C}[z]$. Then this DE has regular-singularities in $z_1=0$, $z_2=1$ and $z_3=\infty$ if and only if for all $j=1,...,n$ the coefficients are

$$p_j(z) = \sum_{k=0}^j p_{jk}(z-1)^{-k}$$

with $p_{jk} \in \mathbb{C}$.

***proof-idea:***

In the article, where I found the above claim, the author refers to Chapter 15.3-15.4 of  the book ([Chap. 15.3 - 15.4](https://archive.org/details/ordinarydifferen029666mbp/page/n377/mode/2up)). So the first thing that came to mind, was using the criterium we have for the coefficients of Fuchsian differential equations ([coeff. Fuchssian DE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuchs_relation#Coefficients_of_a_Fuchsian_equation)). Therefore I first transformed the equation

$$z^n\frac{d^n}{dz^n} + p_1 z^{n-1} \frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}} + ... + p_{n-1}z\frac{d}{dz} + p_n = 0$$

into

$$\frac{d^n}{dz^n} + \tilde{p_1} \frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}} + ... +\tilde{p_{n-1}}\frac{d}{dz} + \tilde{p_n} = 0$$

with $\tilde{p_j}(z) = p_j(z) z^{-j}$. Using the criterium, we get

$$\tilde{p_j}(z) = \prod_{k=1}^2 (z-z_k)^{-j} P_j(z)$$
with $deg(P_j) \leq j$ and thus

$$p_j(z) z^{-j} = z^{-j} (z-1)^{-j} \sum_{k=0}^j P_{k}z^k$$

But now comes my problem: Getting rid of the $z^{-j}$ I end up with the following

$$p_j(z) = \sum_{k=0}^j P_{k} (z-1)^{-j} z^k$$

This clearly is not, what I aimed for. Now I dont know, if I did a mistake, or if this way was wrong to begin with. Thats why Im asking for help...
Im really stuck on this one, so if anyone has an idea, I would really appreciate it! Thx.